# Terraform azure Function App with Enable network injection

Tags: azure, function, azure-functions, terraform

I need help with this issue,

I need to configurate in terraform this option:

[image]

but I don't know how I can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource  [`app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection) can be used to configure the network injection:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "example" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_app_service.example.id
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.example.id
}
```

Comment: @DanielVegaRuiz great, please consider to mark as the correct answer